# Cannot configure Apache2 to disable SSLv3

Tags: apache, ssl

I am trying to run a calendar server (Caldavd).  I ran into trouble when I enabled SSL.  I get the error:
"Unable to Connect Securely

Firefox cannot guarantee the safety of your data on localhost:8443 because it uses SSLv3, a broken security protocol."

I am running on Ubuntu 12.04, have created a self signed certificate, using openssl 1.0.2 (the latest, as far as I can tell), and have added the line
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 
to my site configuration file.

I am a newbie to Apache, not a sysadmin. I understand why Firefox wants to disable SSLv3 but I don't know what else I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have all the weak ciphers disabled. Since the server is internal use OpenSSL.

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443 -cipher 'ALL:!RC4' -no_ssl2 -no_tls1_1 -no_tls1_2
```

If the connection is successful then you know the configurations worked.

How to disable weak ciphers in Apache: https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-disable-weak-ciphers-and-ssl-2.0-in-apache.html

Comment: Thanks for this, but when I ran the openssl command the result showed that the SSL protocol was SSLv3.  I read the weak cipher article and as I am running on Ubuntu 12.04 I copied the crib to my enabled site configuration file (caldavd-ssl), restarted apache2 but the protocol was still showing as SSLv3. Apache2ctl  configtest was happy with the modified file.  Am I making the change in the correct file?